# Significado de tuno en «Antón y el Eco»

Tags: significado

Me encontré hoy con el poema de Francisco de Añón [*Antón y el eco*](http://poemas.flacoman.com/2005/02/antn-y-el-eco-el-borracho-y-el-eco.html) o *El borracho y el eco*, y además de la sonrisa, me dejó una pequeña duda en un fin de estrofa que dice

> El momento es oportuno…
>   —Tuno!
>
> —¿Dónde está el majadero
>   que me toma por carnero?

¿Qué significa tuno en este caso? o mejor ¿por qué Antón se siente tratado como carnero cuando el eco le responde tuno?

Comment: fin del eco : Opor(tuno)

Comment: La versión más larga aparece firmada como de 1858. Los diccionarios de esa época (ver NTLLE) recogen otras acepciones de **bali** que no se encuentran en los actuales, como una serpiente, adornos, una planta, un idioma, una saca que se usaba para llevar la lana en los lavaderos ...

Comment: No se debe ampliar tanto la pregunta a mitad de camino.  Por favor, pon tu material adicional en una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Si bien ambas respuestas conservan un sentido claro, no se muestra claro con la continuación relacionada  *-¿Dónde está el majadero que me toma por carnero?*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuno, majadero y carnero son tres maneras de expresar la misma idea.

> tuno: adj. Pícaro, tunante ([DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=avIaJGc%7CavLh9e7%7CavNZqQL))

Con esta acepcion, se conserva la estructura del poema.

Comment: "no vaya a ser un tunante", por fin entiendo esta frase

Comment: @Mike - ah.  Por curiosidad, en que contexto la oiste?

Comment: Villancico popular Mexicano : "Entre Santos Peregrinos"

Comment: https://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=899999 - Gracias, @Mike.

Comment: El significado de *tuno* parece claro, pero no veo por qué *carnero* vaya a significar lo mismo.

Comment: @Gorpik - Ahora no encuentro la fuente que me dio esa idea originalmente.  Pero me imagino que es parecido a *cabrón*.

Answer (score 0):

El eco está diciéndole «Tú, ¡no!» en respuesta a lo que pregunta Antón

> ¿Burro yo? …
>   … … …
>   … … …
>   … … …
>   — Tú, ¡no!